# How to implement mouse button click event in QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: qt, qt5

I am not able to understand how to emit a signal when we click mouse button on QDoubleSpinBox

I would like to emit the signal mouseButtonCLick when ever the mouse button is clicked.

```
class MyDoubleBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    using QDoubleSpinBox::QDoubleSpinBox;  // inherit c'tors        
    void setSingleStep(double val);     
    void stepBy(int steps) override;

public slots:   
    void setZero();

signals:
    void mouseButtonClick();

private:
    double m_defaultStep = 1.0;
};
```

Comment: Sorry.  It turns out void QAbstractSpinBox::mousePressEvent() is protected :/. Here's a url where they discuss a failed attempt to implement an event filter: https://forum.qt.io/topic/59110/qdoublespinbox-mousepressevent/6. I have sometimes been able to access a child widget, like the QLineEdit in it, directly. I think of it as a poor design decision. I'd file a tracker issue on it.